# Scraping Google with puppeteer extra plugin recaptcha

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, recaptcha, chromium

I am using node and puppeteer with plugin for solving recaptcha at Google search results.

It was working like a charm until yesterday. Google reCaptcha is solved but it not redirects to show search result page after solving captcha as it was done before problems started.

I have noticed that now Google reCaptcha is served with frame and puppeteer extra plugin recaptcha potentially can do it as it's said here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha

My code is:

```
// puppeteer-extra is a drop-in replacement for puppeteer,
// it augments the installed puppeteer with plugin functionality
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')

// add recaptcha plugin and provide it your 2captcha token (= their apiKey)
// 2captcha is the builtin solution provider but others would work as well.
// Please note: You need to add funds to your 2captcha account for this to work
const RecaptchaPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha')
puppeteer.use(
  RecaptchaPlugin({
    provider: {
      id: '2captcha',
      token: 'd4e...' // REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR OWN 2CAPTCHA API KEY ⚡
    },
    visualFeedback: true // colorize reCAPTCHAs (violet = detected, green = solved)
  })
)

// puppeteer usage as normal
puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  //await page.goto('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=google&oq=google&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8')

  // That's it, a single line of code to solve reCAPTCHAs 
  await page.solveRecaptchas()

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation()
  ])
  let bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
  console.log(bodyHTML)
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'response.png', fullPage: true })
  await browser.close()
})
```

and here's the debug:

```
seo@serv:~/google$ DEBUG=puppeteer-extra,puppeteer-extra-plugin:* node test.js

  puppeteer-extra-plugin:base:recaptcha Initialized. +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha Initialized {
  visualFeedback: true,
  throwOnError: false,
  provider: { id: '2captcha', token: 'd4e...' }
} +0ms
  puppeteer-extra plugin registered recaptcha +0ms
  puppeteer-extra no dependencies are missing +1ms
  puppeteer-extra orderPlugins:before [ 'recaptcha' ] +0ms
  puppeteer-extra orderPlugins:after [ 'recaptcha' ] +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha onPageCreated about:blank +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha solveRecaptchas +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha findRecaptchas +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha hasRecaptchaScriptTag true +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha waitForRecaptchaClient - start 2020-05-23T22:04:15.081Z +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha waitForRecaptchaClient - end 2020-05-23T22:04:15.091Z +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha _generateContentScript findRecaptchas undefined +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha findRecaptchas {
  captchas: [
    {
      sitekey: '6LfwuyUTAAAAAOAmoS0fdqijC2PbbdH4kjq62Y1b',
      callback: 'submitCallback',
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      widgetId: 0,
      display: [Object],
      url: 'https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dklima%26oq%3Dgoogle%26aqs%3Dchrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.735j0j7%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26ie%3DUTF-8&q=EgS8pdi4GN67pvYFIhkA8aeDS9yQqQWq3BMCa6xUSD_F653Fxcx7MgFy',
      hasResponseElement: true
    }
  ],
  error: null
} +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha getRecaptchaSolutions +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha:2captcha Requesting solution.. {
  provider: '2captcha',
  id: 'oda83noeflau',
  requestAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:15.100Z
} +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha:2captcha Got response {
  err: null,
  result: {
    id: '63956086379',
    text: '03AGdBq26iX0JWbJGTu1Bbl98SH2ZQQxAsLELiNrf9Iz14ORUZPvdjRgNPuF2dgpERJb1ylQqQyw4dSDs8K-UruIlaeE8K9c064cCHYOeuwvggqV91bzYkZDbX39NUToTr7UDgO0LOTts803ELdwNxp5FRZutEqpwK4aTjzX9u8ROXJ1-v4ozbJofb38-zVnhm1eftXYpLxllJpXonswmha5GJRPIwPjKv4RZCdz6xTQRN1wtOPX4emUPBj2qadsKpTg633JV46sh2c66vT7Syb4BSFajNFfR_GbbFdPlnDcd5_E4gg3kV58c'
  },
  invalid: [Function: bound ]
} +2s
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha getRecaptchaSolutions {
  solutions: [
    {
      provider: '2captcha',
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      requestAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:15.100Z,
      providerCaptchaId: '63956086379',
      text: '03AGdBq26iX0JWbJGTu1Bbl98SH2ZQQxAsLELiNrf9Iz14ORUZPvdjRgNPuF2dgpERJb1ylQqQyw4dSDs8K-UruIlaeE8K9c064cCHYOeuwvggqV91bzYkZDbX39NUToTr7UDgO0LOTts803ELdwNxp5FRZutEqpwK4aTjzX9u8ROXJ1-v4ozbJofb38-zVnhm1eftXYpLxllJpXonswmha5GJRPIwPjKv4RZCdz6xTQRN1wtOPX4emUPBj2qadsKpTg633JV46sh2c66vT7Syb4BSFajNFfR_GbbFdPlnDcd5_E4gg3kV58c',
      responseAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:17.370Z,
      hasSolution: true,
      duration: 2.27
    }
  ],
  error: undefined
} +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha enterRecaptchaSolutions +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha _generateContentScript enterRecaptchaSolutions {
  solutions: [
    {
      provider: '2captcha',
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      requestAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:15.100Z,
      providerCaptchaId: '63956086379',
      text: '03AGdBq26iX0JWbJGTu1Bbl98SH2ZQQxAsLELiNrf9Iz14ORUZPvdjRgNPuF2dgpERJb1ylQqQyw4dSDs8K-UruIlaeE8K9c064cCHYOeuwvggqV91bzYkZDbX39NUToTr7UDgO0LOTts803ELdwNxp5FRZutEqpwK4aTjzX9u8ROXJ1-v4ozbJofb38-zVnhm1eftXYpLxllJpXonswmha5GJRPIwPjKv4RZCdz6xTQRN1wtOPX4emUPBj2qadsKpTg633JV46sh2c66vT7Syb4BSFajNFfR_GbbFdPlnDcd5_E4gg3kV58c',
      responseAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:17.370Z,
      hasSolution: true,
      duration: 2.27
    }
  ]
} +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha enterRecaptchaSolutions {
  solved: [
    {
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      responseElement: true,
      responseCallback: true,
      isSolved: true,
      solvedAt: {}
    }
  ],
  error: undefined
} +0ms
  puppeteer-extra-plugin:recaptcha solveRecaptchas {
  captchas: [
    {
      sitekey: '6LfwuyUTAAAAAOAmoS0fdqijC2PbbdH4kjq62Y1b',
      callback: 'submitCallback',
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      widgetId: 0,
      display: [Object],
      url: 'https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dklima%26oq%3Dgoogle%26aqs%3Dchrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.735j0j7%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26ie%3DUTF-8&q=EgS8pdi4GN67pvYFIhkA8aeDS9yQqQWq3BMCa6xUSD_F653Fxcx7MgFy',
      hasResponseElement: true
    }
  ],
  solutions: [
    {
      provider: '2captcha',
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      requestAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:15.100Z,
      providerCaptchaId: '63956086379',
      text: '03AGdBq26iX0JWbJGTu1Bbl98SH2ZQQxAsLELiNrf9Iz14ORUZPvdjRgNPuF2dgpERJb1ylQqQyw4dSDs8K-UruIlaeE8K9c064cCHYOeuwvggqV91bzYkZDbX39NUToTr7UDgO0LOTts803ELdwNxp5FRZutEqpwK4aTjzX9u8ROXJ1-v4ozbJofb38-zVnhm1eftXYpLxllJpXonswmha5GJRPIwPjKv4RZCdz6xTQRN1wtOPX4emUPBj2qadsKpTg633JV46sh2c66vT7Syb4BSFajNFfR_GbbFdPlnDcd5_E4gg3kV58c',
      responseAt: 2020-05-23T22:04:17.370Z,
      hasSolution: true,
      duration: 2.27
    }
  ],
  solved: [
    {
      id: 'oda83noeflau',
      responseElement: true,
      responseCallback: true,
      isSolved: true,
      solvedAt: {}
    }
  ],
  error: undefined
} +0ms

<div style="max-width:400px;">
<hr noshade="" size="1" style="color:#ccc; background-color:#ccc;"><br>
<form id="captcha-form" action="index" method="post">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/BT5UwN2jyUJCo7TdbwTYi_58/recaptcha__en.js"></script><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async="" defer=""></script>
<script>var submitCallback = function(response) {document.getElementById('captcha-form').submit();};</script>
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfwuyUTAAAAAOAmoS0fdqijC2PbbdH4kjq62Y1b" data-callback="submitCallback" data-s="cojAJSZCdLw81Mw5102PzG5LCy2bEgY-Qgb0-Oa8bdMLsAjcUB7GHfYlSTUsLPcez0e4N8BYqFCc-jZ-XabU9E0GKLwuWbMScAFsxh0IqK2nuqHNLT3f4jCHZU113pPZQt8Wc56k250zig5yoYxpMvWQ85CIvEfWfG3BrT60dccP788N2aLdbn12pmWzOsKuLt893rL8KxnpaMHs4ZsiPkUJdCsAy6AzaRAinNs4eV23RDtrGHNi-u0"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LfwuyUTAAAAAOAmoS0fdqijC2PbbdH4kjq62Y1b&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=BT5UwN2jyUJCo7TdbwTYi_58&amp;size=normal&amp;s=cojAJSZCdLw81Mw5102PzG5LCy2bEgY-Qgb0-Oa8bdMLsAjcUB7GHfYlSTUsLPcez0e4N8BYqFCc-jZ-XabU9E0GKLwuWbMScAFsxh0IqK2nuqHNLT3f4jCHZU113pPZQt8Wc56k250zig5yoYxpMvWQ85CIvEfWfG3BrT60dccP788N2aLdbn12pmWzOsKuLt893rL8KxnpaMHs4ZsiPkUJdCsAy6AzaRAinNs4eV23RDtrGHNi-u0&amp;cb=r91kon3sihd2" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-hui2ii7cbhhz" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="EgS8pdi4GN67pvYFIhkA8aeDS9yQqQWq3BMCa6xUSD_F653Fxcx7MgFy"><input type="hidden" name="continue" value="https://www.google.com/search?q=klima&amp;oq=google&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.735j0j7&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8">
</form>
<hr noshade="" size="1" style="color:#ccc; background-color:#ccc;">

<div style="font-size:13px;">
<b>About this page</b><br><br>

Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.  This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot.  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('infoDiv').style.display='block';">Why did this happen?</a><br><br>

<div id="infoDiv" style="display:none; background-color:#eee; padding:10px; margin:0 0 15px 0; line-height:1.4em;">
This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the <a href="//www.google.com/policies/terms/">Terms of Service</a>. The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.  In the meantime, solving the above CAPTCHA will let you continue to use our services.<br><br>This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests.  If you share your network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different computer using the same IP address may be responsible.  <a href="//support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Learn more</a><br><br>Sometimes you may be asked to solve the CAPTCHA if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.
</div>

IP address: x.x.x.x<br>Time: 2020-05-23T22:04:17Z<br>URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=klima&amp;oq=google&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.735j0j7&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Captcha is solved but I am not redirected to the Google search results page :(

Tried also with iframe solution, but at the debug it says that hasn't found any captcha.

```
// Loop over all potential frames on that page
for (const frame of page.mainFrame().childFrames()) {
  // Attempt to solve any potential reCAPTCHAs in those frames
  await frame.solveRecaptchas()
}
```

I need help - I don't know node well. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: puppeteer needs to be updated as it was said here: https://2captcha.com/blog/google-search-recaptcha

Comment: Those Google SERPs have a callback that needs to get called, I'm not sure if the plugin does this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab "data-s" attribute value and send it to captcha solving provider. At least AntiCaptcha is supporting it now.

Comment: Yes, I got also email from 2captcha, and they are supporting it too now. I don't know how to upgrade plugin, looked into code but I am not so familiar with JavaScript